# Convert text to bytes from Bash shell?

Tags: bash, shell, encoding, command-line, utility

How can a text string be turned into UTF-8 encoded bytes using Bash and/or common Linux command line utilities?  For example, in Python one would do:

```
"Six of one, ½ dozen of the other".encode('utf-8')
b'Six of one, \xc2\xbd dozen of the other'
```

Is there a way to do this in pure Bash:

```
STR="Six of one, ½ dozen of the other"
<utility_or_bash_command_here> --encoding='utf-8' $STR
'Six of one, \xc2\xbd dozen of the other'
```

Comment: _Avoid answering questions in comments._

Comment: bash doesn't have a clear "text string" vs. "bytes" distinction. When you use `STR="Six of one, ½ dozen of the other"`, it's *already* basically a list of bytes (more accurately, a [C string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling)), maybe in UTF-8 encoding, maybe in something else. Try `echo "$STR" | od -x`, and you'll probably see "bdc2" in the results. So I'm not really clear what you're trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl to the rescue!

```
echo "$STR" | perl -pe 's/([^x\0-\x7f])/"\\x" . sprintf "%x", ord $1/ge'
```

The `/e` modifier allows to include code into the replacement part of the `s///` substitution, which in this case converts [ord](http://p3rl.org/ord) to hex via [sprintf](http://p3rl.org/sprintf).

Answer (score 3):

Python to the rescue!

```sh
alias encode='python3 -c "from sys import stdin; print(stdin.read().encode(\"utf-8\"))"'
```

```sh
root@kali-linux:~# echo "½ " | encode
b'\xc2\xbd \n'
```

Also, you can remove `b''` with some sed/awk thingy if you want.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, and unvoted for trying, but IIRC I specifically couldn't use Python to solve this problem and had to rely on bash utilities, which I guess I didn't make clear in the question.  If Python is available, another option is `encode() { python3 -c "print('$1'.encode())" ; }` and calling `encode "½ "`

Comment: I too didn't realize you specifically asked for bash utils/pure bash. I saw perl answer so gave python answer. My bad

Answer (score 0):

I adapted Machinexa's nice answer a little for my needs

- `encoding="utf-8"` is the default so no need to pass
- more concise to just import sys and use directly
- Here I'm looking to make a unique `set` not a `list` or concatenated bytestring

```bash
alias encode='python3 -c "import sys; enc = sys.stdin.read().encode(); print(set(enc))"'
```

So then I can get a set without repetition:

```bash
printf "hell0\x0\nworld\n:-)\x0:-(\n" | \
  grep -a "[[:cntrl:]]" -o | \
  perl -pe 's/([^x\0-\x7f])/"\\x" . sprintf "%x", ord $1/ge' | \
  encode
```

⇣

```
{b'\x00'}
```

and then if you wanted to drop the Python byte repr `b''` and the backslash:

```bash
alias encode='python3 -c "from sys import stdin; encoded = stdin.read().encode(\"utf-8\"); s = set(encoded.splitlines()[:-1]); print({repr(char)[3:-1] for char in s})"'
```

which for the previous command gives `{'x00'}` instead